# Python - How to copy all data out of an array

Tags: python, json, list, firebase

Currently I am exporting a database from firebase into a JSON but it is coming out in as an array.

```
[{"ConnectionTime": 19.23262298107147, "objectId": "01331oxpVT", "FirmwareRevision": "201504270003 Img-B", "DeviceID": "EDF02C74-6518-489E-8751-25C58F8C830D", "PeripheralType": 4, "updatedAt": "2015-10-09T04:01:39.569Z", "Model": "Bean", "HardwareRevision": "E", "Serial": "Serial Number", "createdAt": "2015-10-09T04:01:39.569Z", "Manufacturer": "Punch Through Design"}, {"ConnectionTime": 0.3193170428276062, "objectId": "018Mv1g6I8", "DeviceID": "42635033-DF3A-4109-A633-C3AB829BE114", "PeripheralType": 2, "updatedAt": "2015-12-08T04:20:41.950Z", "createdAt": "2015-12-08T04:20:41.950Z"}]
```

And then I get this error - `Start of array encountered without start of object.'}]`

How can I change this to not be an Array and just a list of data. I also need a line break between each set of data but Im assuming once I get the data out of the array the code I currently have will do that. My code is below. Thanks for the help!

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://dataworks-356fa.firebaseio.com/')
result = firebase.get('/connection_info_parse', None)
# id_keys = map(str, result.keys()) #filter out ID names


with open("firetobqrestore1.json", "w") as outfile:
#   for id in id_keys:
  json.dump(result, outfile, indent=None)
  outfile.write("\n")
```

Comment: JSON can contain arrays... What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: Yes  but I am exporting this into BigQuery and I need to pull it out of the array for BigQuery to accept it

Comment: I see you have `for id in id_keys:`, so did you try something like `for x in result`? And just `print(x)` to see what that is?

Comment: That part was used for another database I was exporting where I had to filter out the key for each entry but for some reason this database doesn't include the keys when the file is exported @cricket_007. I will try this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something in your workflow wants newline delimited JSON, although you haven't made it explicitly clear what is giving you this error.

With that caveat, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import json

with open("firetobqrestore1.json", "w") as outfile:
    for line in result:
        json.dump(line, outfile, indent=None)
        outfile.write("\n")
```

This will write individual json objects to each line.

This also assumes that `result` is an actual python object rather than a JSON string. If it's a string you will need to parse it first with something like:

```
result = json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the elements of the list are not parsed ( they are strings), then loop through the list and convert each element to a json using json.loads(). Then, you can use json.dumps()

In case the elements of the list are already parsed,then just loop through the list and use json.dumps().

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean

Comment: Why would `json.loads()` be needed? It's already in a Python list, so only `dumps()` the elements